# ASM lodsw to mov and inc

Tags: assembly, nasm, mov

I have in my simple program loaded some strings into

```
mov si, song
```

witch load:

```
song:
%if 1
dw E0, C, A, E1, C, A, E2, B, A, E3, C, B
%endif
dw E0, C, A, E1, C, A, 0

E0 equ 14000 etc...
```

Im loading elements from it with

```
 lodsw; (one transition use three of them)
```

And I need to do it with

```
 mov and inc
```

I tried

```
mov ax, [si+dx]
inc dx
```

But this dont want to work,
Any ideas

Comment: Can you show the full code and explain more clearly what doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lodsw` is equivalent (if omitting flags) to

```
mov ax, word [si]
add si, 2
```

I am not sure you can use `dx` in an address expression like `[si+dx]` (in 16-bit mode, only `si`, `di`, `bp` and `bx` are index registers). If you don't want to change `si`, use `bx`.

(By the way: do you really want to write 16-bit code? It's quite outdated. NASM compiles 32-bit code perfectly.)

Answer (score 0):

Since your table consists of "dw" (16bit values), you'll need increment dx by 2

```
mov ax, [si+dx]
inc dx
inc dx
```

or just

```
mov ax, [si+dx]
add dx, 2
```

Comment: It wouldn't work anyway, since `si+dx` [isn't a valid register combination for real mode effective addresses](http://wiki.osdev.org/Real_Mode#Addressing_Modes).